# Pass array of srtucts as WCF method parameter in HTTP GET

Tags: wcf, arrays, http, struct, get

i have a WCF Method that receives array of structs.
the struct contains two strings "Key" and "Value":

```
public struct mydata
{
    public String key;
    public String value;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IBasicService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ReceiveStructsOfData?myDataArray={???????? WHAT DO I WRITE HERE?????}")] 
    void ReceiveStructsOfData(mydata[] myDataArray);

}
```

i want the method to support HTTP "GET". 
i already know how to config a WCF to support "GET" ( endpoint and WebGETAttribute).
What do i write in the UriTemplate of WebGet ( see above example) ??

how will the Client code look like using Framework 2.0 (HttpWebRequest) ?

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/BasicWCF/BasicService.svc/ReceiveStructsOfData?myDataArray={???????? WHAT DO I WRITE HERE?????}");
        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

The thing you provide between the curly braces is the name of the parameter, which will be substituted by a value. So the service method would look like:

```
[OperationContract]  
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "ReceiveStructsOfData?myDataArray={myDataArray}")]  
void ReceiveStructsOfData(mydata[] myDataArray)
{
}
```

Notice the string between the braces is the same as the parameter name - that's how the mapping of requests to methods is done.

When calling the service, you should take care to serialize the array to a string. After all, you are passing parameters in the URL, which is itself a string. Normally I wouldn't pass such a param to a GET method. If it was a PUT method and you were passing params in the request (not the URL), then you could serialize them as JSON or XML, depending on the service.

Comment: why wouldn't you pass such a param to a "GET" method ?

Comment: Normally I would implement a RESTful service, where a GET operation only returns a resource or a collection of resources. If we assume that's the role of the GET operation, then the only thing that such a parameter would be used for is to filter the result. And in that case I would use a string filter expression of some kind, not an array of structs. But that's the way I would go, I'm not saying all the rest is wrong.